# RabbitMQ Erlang Cookie

Tags: rabbitmq

I have RabiitMQ running on a CentOS 5.5 box, with Erlang R15B01.  RabbitMQ was running just swell until I upgraded to the latest version (2.8.4).

When I startup RabbitMQ using the command:

```
/etc/init.d/rabbitmq start
```

In the RabbitMQ startup_log I'm seeing the following:

```
{error_logger,{{2012,7,11},{11,44,15}},"Cookie file /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie mus be accessible by owner only",[]}
```

The Erlang cookie has the following permissions:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 17 Jul 10 12:20 .erlang.cookie
```

Has anyone else experienced this? Or does anyone have some troubleshooting steps I could follow?

Many thanks,
Risteard

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, that error message tells you exactly what needs to happen:

```
$ chmod 600 /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
```

Comment: you saved my live :)

Comment: I have a similar problem with RMQ not being able to write to mnesia via docker, any thoughts there?